# F# Function which takes label as an argument

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming, record

F# newbie here and trying to find the 'functional way' of doing things.

I have an array of records

```
type Node = {Value: int; Height: int; Width: int}
let dummyData = [|
    {Value = 1000; Height = 200;  Width = 200}
    {Value = 500;  Height = 1000; Width = 500}
    {Value = 2000; Height = 500;  Width = 100}
    |]
```

I am looking to find the smallest value of each of the labels in the record. For each label, I can find write a function to find the minimum value using Array.minBy, for example:

```
let findMinHeight xs = 
    let item = 
        xs |> Array.minBy (fun x -> x.Height)
    item.Height
```

However this feels cumbersome, as in this example I'd need to write essentially the same function 3 times, once for each label. 
Is it possible to construct a single function which takes in the array along with the specific label and returns the appropriate minimum value?

I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
let minHeight = findMin dummyData Height
let minWidth  = findMin dummyData Width
let minValue  = findMin dummyData Value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record labels are not "first-class" values that could be passed as arguments to functions. However, you can write a `findMin` function that takes another function as an argument - and then give it a function that takes `Node` and returns one of the labels of your record:

So, we add an argument `f` of type `Node -> 'T` (the type `'T` is a generic type parameter, so the function can work with labels of different types as long as they are comparable). The function is used in `minBy` and then to get the property of the resulting `item`:

```
let findMin (f:Node -> 'T) xs = 
    let item = xs |> Array.minBy f
    f item
```

To use it, you can write (I added `f` as the first argument, so we can write code using the pipelining operator):

```
dummyData |> findMin (fun n -> n.Height)
dummyData |> findMin (fun n -> n.Width)
```